Unhandled Rejection: MongoServerSelectionError
I am trying to solve an issue that's been happening to me for a little while now. Most of my database operations can be performed without any issues, but it seems like I am randomly getting MongoServerSelectionErrors which cause my application to crash.
This is happening both in my local and production environment, and I haven't found any way to reliably reproduce it.
I'm using
"mongodb": "^6.5.0",
"mongoose": "^8.3.1",

And for next-auth I'm also using "@auth/mongodb-adapter": "^2.6.0" (not sure if it could be related to this one)
Here is the entire error message taken from my Vercel logs:
Unhandled Rejection: MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
at EventTarget.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.5.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:289:34)
at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:786:20)
at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:721:26)
at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:369:10)
at TimeoutController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:403:5)
at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.5.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:976:92)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'ac-ygz1cvo-shard-00-00.frnyejo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-ygz1cvo-shard-00-01.frnyejo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-ygz1cvo-shard-00-02.frnyejo.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-k31dqm-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

My mongo config file:
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!uri) {
  console.error("⚠️ MONGODB_URI missing from .env");
} else {
  try {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    clientPromise = client.connect();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("MongoDB client error: " + err);
  }
}

export default clientPromise;

And mongoose config file:
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let mongooseConnection = null;

const connectMongo = async () => {
  if (mongooseConnection) {
    return mongooseConnection;
  }

  if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error("MONGODB_URI is not defined");
  }

  try {
    const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    });
    mongooseConnection = db;
    return db;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Mongoose connection error: " + e);
    throw e;
  }
};

export default connectMongo;

Also, here's a screenshot from my Mongo Compass Monitoring tab
Has anyone had this issue and found a way to solve it?
I have tried changing parameters in the connection options, but without any success.

At the moment there are two ways in this code to connect with MongoDB.
-using mongoose and mongoDB driver. In fact only one code would suffice. mongoose has certain advantages like in case of losing connection, it would automatically try to reconnect. Another thing to convey is that at present this code uses mongoDB driver to connect, and the mongoose code is not getting executed. This is understood from the error log. Also in case of using mongoose to connect, please leave everything to default, and see them in action. ...

...At present a few settings have already changed, it may not be required. For testing, please change this line const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000, socketTimeoutMS: 45000, heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, }); to const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

The details about the connection attempt to each node would be in the [ServerDescription] - can you expand that part of the error?

I don't think I can expand that part unfortunately, at least from what I see in my Vercel logs there is no option to do so.
